# Why font-size is not applied to raw cell content

Tags: html, css

I have class definition:

```
.small, td.small, td.small > nobr, td.small > a
{
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

That makes text inside of anchor in the cell looking smaller.

But style is not applied if I put text in cell without anchor.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="small">
                <a href="...">Small content</a>
            </td>
            <td>Should be smaller as well</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Why? How to make raw text looking smaller without introducing another wrapper?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you forgot to put the class "small" on the second `<td>` element.  It should look like this:

```
<td class="small">
   <a href="...">Small content</a>
</td>
<td class="small">Should be smaller as well</td>
```

Comment: Heh, thank you! That was stupid typo from my side during posting the question, though, this revealed another problem, please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156712/why-style-is-applied-twice

Answer (score 0):

Well it is a bad habit to use just plain text, without `<p>text</p>` tags, but whatever you want.

And the problem is that you did not specify the pure `td {font-size: 90%}`,  you just have it for the small class defined. So just add that piece of code to your styles and it should work.