# Why style is applied twice?

Tags: html, css

I have class definition:

```
.small, td.small, td.small > nobr, td.small > a
{
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

The purpose is to make text smaller. That should be applied to anything: text in anchor, text in cell, etc.

But in fact, style is applied TWICE if anchor is inside of the cell:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="small">
                <a href="...">VERY small content</a>
            </td>
            <td class="small">Smaller text - looks as required</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Why? How to make sure that style is applied only once?

Thank you.

Comment: if you use em or % values for font-size they are calculated from the size of the closest parent where it is define, if no font-size declaration are found it uses browszes defaut setting. you may use the rem unit that refers to browser defaut or html/body's declaration. so you better use the rem unit here i believe:)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last part of the style, `td.small > a`.  Then it will get applied to everything inside the `<td>`.  Note, I changed the size of the font to 60% just so that the size change is apparent.

```css
.small, td.small, td.small > nobr
{
    font-size: 60%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="small">
                <a href="...">Small content</a>
            </td>
            <td class="small">Should be smaller as well</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```